# Laravel duplicate checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a laravel application. I want to Edit information out of a table. this table is linked to another table with a pivot table. Because i want to add multiple 'roles' to a 'file'.

I want to be able to check the checkboxes with the roles that are already connected to the specific file.

If i try to edit a file that has multiple roles, the checkboxes multiply by the amount of roles that are connected to that file. 1 role = normal amount of checkboxes, 2 roles = 2 checkboxes of all roles.
I also noticed that the first connected role checked the first of the duplicate checkboxes, but the second connected role checked the second of the duplicate checkboxes. this also happens with the 3rd and so on.

[image]

Table a (file):
[image]
Table b (role):
[image]
Pivot table:
[image]

Edit.blade code (only the checkboxes):

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{('Role')}}</label>
                @foreach($allroles as $rol)
                @foreach($file_role as $file_roles)
                <label><input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$rol->id}}" @if($rol->id == $file_roles->role_id) checked=checked @endif>{{$rol->name}}</label>
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

controller:

```
public function edit($id, Request $request, )
    {
        $files = File::all();
        $fileEdit = File::find($id);
        $languages = Language::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $subfolder = Subfolder::all();
     
        $users = User::all();
        $roles = Role::all();
        $allroles = Role::all();
        $file_role = File_Role::where('file_id', '=', $id)->get();
        $file_subfolder = File_Subfolder::all();
       // dd($file_role);
        return view('admin.file.index', compact('files', 'fileEdit', 'languages', 'tags', 'subfolder' ,'users', 'roles', 'allroles' ,'file_role', 'file_subfolder'));
    }
```

If i need to add any extra information i will gladly do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{('Role')}}</label>
                @foreach($allroles as $rol)
                
                <label><input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$rol->id}}" @if($rol->id == $file_roles->role_id) checked=checked @endif>{{$rol->name}}</label>
                @endforeach
              
            </div>
```

i just had to remove 1 foreach.
this made it loop thru it twice